# Computing the spectrum of a lagrangian in field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, sigma-models

I have the following lagrangian density:

$$L = \bar{\psi}i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu \psi 
- g\bar{\psi}(\sigma + i\gamma^5\pi)\psi +
\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \sigma)^2+
\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu \pi)^2
-V(\sigma^2 + \pi^2)$$

where $\pi$ and $\sigma$ are scalar fields.

I have show that this lagrangian density is invariant under a chiral symmetry and has a conserved current.
Now the question I'm attempting asks the following:

> What is the spectrum of theory when $V(\sigma^2 + \pi^2) = \lambda(\sigma^2 + \pi^2 - c^2)^2$?

Now I don't quite understand how to do this problem. I assume that by spectrum the question means what kind of particle you obtain in that specific condition. Am I right? If so, how do I go about computing the spectrum? I thought about plugging the value in the lagrangian and then working out the EOMs but not sure how that would help anything.

Comment: (a) Are you sure the potential isn't $V(\sigma^2+\pi^2)=\lambda(\sigma^2+\pi^2-c^2)^2$? (b) Forget about field theory; if you were given a Lagrangian in classical mechanics, and asked to find the frequency of small oscillations around a stable minimum, would you be able to solve this problem? If so the math is basically the same here. The question is: what are the degrees of freedom and what are the masses of those degrees of freedom (aka what are the normal modes and frequency of small oscillations of the normal modes).

Comment: Yes, you're right that was a typo. Ok in that case what I would do is to find the minimum of the potential, then Taylor expand around that point. Would that be the correct way to proceed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should end up with a quadratic Lagrangian. If you ignore the spatial derivative terms, it will have the form $ \sum_{ij} Z_{ij} \dot{q}_i \dot{q}_j - V_{ij} q^i q^j $. In general you then want to try and diagonalize $Z$ and $V$ (though you might not be able to diagonalize them simultaneously). Probably you will end up with a common special case, $\frac{1}{2} \dot{q}_i^2 - \frac{1}{2} m^2_{ij} q^i q^j$. Then the spectrum will follow from diagonalizing the mass matrix $m^2_{ij}$. (In particular the spectrum is given by the eigenvalues of the mass matrix)